# How to make a count-down function work in netlogo

Tags: countdown, netlogo

I'm having some difficulty with my code for a bigger program in net logo that i am working on! I'm attempting to start at a count at 15 and then count down to zero, with cell death occurring at zero. For some reason, my turtles each start off at a different number and then instead of decreasing by 1 count per tick, they decrease by various increments until zero. i'm sure its a silly mistake that i should be catching but i'v been staring at the screen for a long time and am getting frustrated so figured i would reach out to my fellow programmers

Comment: If Alan's answer doesn't help you, you'll need to show us your code.

Answer (score 2):

You do not provide much context for you question, but here is an example that seems to meet your needs.  Enter the code below in the `Code` tab and then enter `setup go show [lifespan] of turtles` at the command line.

```
turtles-own [lifespan]

to setup
  ca
  crt 20 [init-turtle]
end

to go
  ask turtles [age]
end

to init-turtle
  set lifespan 15
  fd 5
end

to age
  set lifespan (lifespan - 1)
  if (lifespan <= 0) [die]
end
```